# How to keep Ubuntu from switching audio output to monitor when plugged in

Tags: sound, pulseaudio

I'm running standard Ubuntu 18.04. When I attach an Apple 27 inch Cinema Display, the default audio switches to the monitor, even though I want to continue using the built-in laptop audio via headphones. The display has a USB which is plugged in, too (for webcam, adjust brightness), but I think the audio might go over the USB, too. However it works, the default audio output switches and I have to go into Settings to switch it back every time. Can I set a default audio output that sticks or disable auto-switching in Ubuntu?